# Couchbase N1QL nested json query with variable key

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have documents. How can I write a query with  nested json field?
**Query**: Count value greater than 3  **output**: doc-1 and doc-3

Doc-1

```
"1": {
    "count":4,
    "name": "pen"
}
```

Doc-2

```
"2": {
    "count":1,
    "name": "eraser"
}
```

Doc-3

```
"3": {
    "count":43,
    "name": "book"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the dynamic object (OBJECT_VALUES(), OBJECT_NAMES(), OBJECT_PAIRS()) into ARRAY and use ANY clause
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/objectfun.html

```
SELECT b.*
FROM mybucket AS b
WHERE ANY v IN OBJECT_VALUES(b) SATISFIES v.`count` > 3 END;
```

Comment: An index must be created for the query to run.:   CREATE index idx_count ON  mybucket (DISTINCT ARRAY v. count FOR v IN OBJECT_VALUES(mybucket) END);